# Is there a way to monitor the memory used by mathematica as a dynamic expression?

Tags: memory, kernel, monitoring, system-performance

I always use the terminal's htop for this, but wouldn't it be nice to visualize per kernel the memory used in a dynamic expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might come close to your need;

```
Dynamic[Refresh[MemoryInUse[], UpdateInterval -> 1]]
```

This will update every second the amount of memory used by the kernel.